# The meaning of third time is the charm

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

If the third time is the charm, then what is the first and second? Is there a fourth?

Comment: See: [Origin of the phrases “third time’s the charm” and “third time lucky”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23161/origin-of-the-phrases-third-time-s-the-charm-and-third-time-lucky)

Comment: Obviously, the first and second are **uncharmed** and the fourth is the Luck of the Irish(four leaf clovers!), Good question though.

Answer (score 2):

*Third time is a charm* is an idiom which means on your third try you're likely to succeed after failing two times.

It is often used as a phrase to encourage someone to try for the third time even after that person has failed at that thing two times earlier, making him realize that his efforts might give him the results on his third time.

You just have to keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

*'third time’s **a** charm'* or *'third time’s **the** charm'* is an idiom - there isn't a correlating first, second or fourth time. A similar expression is '*third time lucky*'.

There is an interesting post on [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23161/origin-of-the-phrases-third-time-s-the-charm-and-third-time-lucky) that attributes the origin of this expression to Shakespeare's [The Merry Wives of Windsor](http://books.google.com/books?id=FU2U2eXY5JoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Merry%20wives%20of%20windsor&hl=en&ei=L0S6Tb7NCZD1gAe3y528Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=this%20is%20the%20third%20time&f=false).

As to why the number '3' is used (and it pops up in other expressions, such as 'try, try and try again'), there are a number of arguments. One argument is the Holy Trinity, and that by extension, goodness or luck is associated with the number three.

The most likely reason can be found [here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/third-time-lucky.html):

> It seems more likely that it is just a folk belief that, having had
>   setbacks, we ought to persevere and not give up. This is enshrined in
>   the phrase 'try, try and try again'. Three seems to be the right
>   number of times to try. Two isn't enough but four is too many.

Answer (score 0):

Third time's the charm (lucky) 
Proverb. The third time you try to do something, it will work.

> I've called her twice, but she doesn't answer her phone. – Try again. The third time's the charm.

That means the third time you will be lucky.
"Three" was a lucky numeral in ancient times.
Compare:

> German . Aller guten Dinge sind drei.
>
> French  Toutes les bonnes choses sont au nombre de trois.
>
> Russian.Бог любит Троицу. God loves the Trinity.

You can add your examples. 
All the proverbs originated from

> Latin. Numero deus impare gaudet.(God loves an odd number)
>   Virgil The Eclogues. 8, 75.